In Replit i am not getting any out put or blurr output
enter image description hereI am doing 100 days of code project. So i am using rep-lit to store my code.When i run my code it is showing blur(i have attached the image also). I see this blur on output section on right side and i don't know, why it is there.few days back it was working fine.I have never seen this problem previously.
Even i tried to to new account and login again in different repositories.But i can see the same error again.
